# Socket connection won't work between smartphone and computer

Tags: java, c#, sockets, router

I have a C# WPF application that uses TCPListener to start a Server in my computer, and an android app that works as a client. It works perfectly when I start the server and emulate the app in my computer, but most of the time it just doesn't work when I use my smartphone to connect to my computer, it only works some times after I restarted my router DHCP and my smartphone.

If you need, here's the connection code

Server:

```
private static IPAddress ipAd;
private static TcpListener server;
private static TcpClient client;

public static void start() {
    //Already tried with both
    ipAd = IPAddress.Parse(TCPServer.GetLocalIPAddress());
    //ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); 

    server = new TcpListener(ipAd, 1209);
    client = default(TcpClient);
    try {
         server.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Server started");
    } catch {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to start server");
    }
```

Client:

```
Socket socket = null;
String response = new String();
try{
    //connect This ipAddress is the same in my desktop
    InetAddress ipAd = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
    socket = new Socket(ipAd, 1209);
    //send
    DataOutputStream DOS = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    DOS.write(message.getBytes());
}
...
```

Thanks for your time, I've should had dedicated more to my Computer Networks class...

Should I redirect some specific port? Have some specific configurations in my router/firewall? I think I'm missing something

Comment: I kind of doubt it's related to your router. What error do you get when it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work when your devices located in the same network in terms of IP routing. However even part of the most simple SOHO grade WiFi routers/AP enable so called device isolation, denying access from wifi devices in the network access between them or to clients, connected with ethernet.

To make this setup work reliably you need to ensure the following:

1. Use external address of your router in the mobile application. (You can discover it browsing  http://whatismyip.org from the server)
2. Setup port forwarding in your router for particular port to particular IP in your internal network.

As for privided source code, you'd rather use 0.0.0.0 as bind address in the server app, because default .NET implementation will select first available IP address and it may be not the one you're using for connection in the mobile app or not related to the same network. This approach may have security and convenience (coexistence) problems in case of complex networking setup, but will work good for most of the cases.